# .NET CORE Publish Folder Profile via Command line not working

Tags: deployment, .net-core

I've created a .NET CORE application and when using Visual Studio I was able to create a publish profile and successfully deploy it when using Visual Studio. When I attempt to use the documentation recommended approach via command line it does not use the publish profile specified and just builds the default debug build and drops it into the bin/debug folder. Here is my publish Profile:

ReleaseProfile.pubxml

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>5a906ff1-d02c-41f7-8912-445f66e15bff</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish\win10-x64</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I run the command `dotnet publish App.API.csproj /p:PublishProfile=ReleaseProfile`

Am I doing something wrong? Because it appears that I should be able to reference the publish profile that I used inside Visual Studio to run the same publish action via the command line.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62954314/73573

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following:

1. Use this if your `.pubxml` file is located in `Properties` folder.

```sh
dotnet publish <CSPROJ_LOCATION> /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=<PROFILE_LOCATION>
```

2. Use this if your `.pubxml` file is **NOT** located in `Properties` folder.

```sh
dotnet publish <CSPROJ_LOCATION> /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfileFullPath=<PROFILE_LOCATION>
```

Answer (score 0):

The /p flag on `dotnet publish` doesn't seem to exist/be documented.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21

Answer (score 0):

From palindrom  -- See [stackoverflow.com/a/62954314/73573](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62954314/73573)

If publishing to a folder, add another property.

For example, if you have this:

```
<PublishUrl>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\IISC</PublishUrl>
```

Add this property:

```
<PublishDir>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\IISC</PublishDir>
```