# dotnet publish profile ignores pubxml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I have the following pubxml file which I created via Visual Studio 2019:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>143a6329-27d9-474e-9521-835be634c293</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

When I run `dotnet.exe publish src\MyProject.Web.sln -p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\ProductionPublish.pubxml` Release does not contain anything and publish happens on Debug folder (debug build). Whys does this happens and pubxml is ignored?

Update #1

```
Structure
src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj
src\MyProject.Utils\ect.Utils.csproj
src\MyProject.Web\MyProject.Web.csproj
src\MyProject.Web.sln
```

and the path of the pubxml

```
src\MyProject.Web\Properties\PublishProfiles\ProductionPublish.pubxml
```

Comment: You have the properties folder under solution? Or under one of the project in solution?

Comment: Updated my post please check

Comment: You are trying to publish solution. You should run `dotnet publish` command from MyProject.Web folder. This will publish web application which you can deploy to web server. You don't need to pass `src\MyProject.Web.sln` parameter to `dotnet publish` command when run from the web project folder.

Comment: I switched to what you said ```dotnet.exe publish Radius.MicroServices.CySec.Web.csproj -p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\ProductionPublish.pubxml``` and still the same result

Answer (score 29):

You need the use following command:

```
dotnet build -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```

- It's `build`, not `publish`.
- Even if my FolderProfile's configuration is set to Release, I had to
  include `-c Release` because otherwise dependent projects were built
  with debug configuration.
- Files not copied to target location if called without `/p:DeployOnBuild=true`.
- Just the name `FolderProfile` -without extension- is enough for the
  profile file. Or you can give the path
  `/p:PublishProfile=Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml`

See [Folder publish example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#folder-publish-example) from Microsoft Docs.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I wanted to use a publish profile via 'dotnet publish' with the profile passed as a parameter but it never worked. This solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: indeed thanks. `dotnet publish` was ok in net5, but after upgrading to net6, it does not work any more for me. This is the only command that worked for me

Comment: Thank you... the MS Documentation fails to mention any of the deploy on build or release params.. that sorted it out for me

Comment: Although this answer says `It's build, not publish`, if I follow the link to the "Folder publish example", the documentation is saying that both "dotnet publish" and "dotnet build" should both work; however, I can categorically state that `dotnet publish` is not working for me - it completely ignores the supplied profile, and just publishes within the project's folder. I had got `msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true myproject  /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile` working before I found this page, and at least that re-uses the previous publish configuration (e.g. Release|AnyCPU); but I might use this.

Comment: This is working for me; but one other thing to add: the only output from this command-line makes it look like it is only publishing locally (like `dotnet publish` does, when it completely ignores the supplied profile); however, the clue that this is working properly is that it takes longer, and the files are definitely being sent to the remote location. At least the `msbuild` command's output actually mentions where it is sending the files.

Comment: Thanks man, how fucking confusing do they have to make this...

Answer (score 8):

Found a solution on VS2022 and Core 6 to publish to an specific folder without indicating the output path on the CLI.

I created a profile called IISC

[image]

If you open that publish profile, you will see the PublishUrl property as follows

```
<PublishUrl>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\IISC</PublishUrl>
```

In My case I'm publishing to the solution folder bin\releas....\IISC

The trick is to add another propery called PublishDir

```
<PublishDir>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\IISC</PublishDir>
```

Now you can publish with this:

```
dotnet publish -c Release /p:PublishProfile=IISC
```

Find Bellow My complete Profile with and addition of an environment variable specific for this profile and and item group to exclude all the appsettings except for appsettings.json and appsettings.IISC.json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT>iisc</ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>true</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\IISC</PublishUrl>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\IISC</PublishDir>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>3e4c25a6-2051-4ccc-a518-645d46d120dd</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="appsettings.*.json">
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Update="appsettings.$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT).json">
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: This should be selected as the answer. Visual Studio fails to add the <PublishDir>" tag to the *.pubxml file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna answer for those who, like me, do want to use the **publish** command, because it's been designed to do so.

According to [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#options) section on **publish** command, you can use the options **configuration** and **output** to solve your problem:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o "<where you want>" -p:PublishProfile=<your profile name>
```

Note that **where you want** can be an absolute path and **your profile name** is only the name of profile, without "pubxml" and without the relative path (IF AND ONLY IF the profile is in "<project_folder>/Properties/PublishProfiles").

Comment: Thanks, this works. Adding the "<PublishDir>" tag to the *.pubxml file as noted in Gerardo Verrone's answer also works, and his solution allows you to remove the -o "<where you want>" item from the cli command.

Comment: seems like it ignores the "Delete existing files" flag

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2         
        inputs:
          command: 'publish'
          projects: '$(project)'
          publishWebProjects: false
          arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration) /p:PublishProfile=MyProfile /p:password=$(MYPASSWD)'
```